# Como usar un apikey en una función especifica. AWS serverless

Tags: api, aws, lambda, yml

Necesito ayuda. he estado leyendo la documentación pero no encuentro una forma de hacer lo siguiente. Supongamos que tengo dos apikeys en el archivo serveless.yml:

```
custom:
  apiKeys:
   - name: keyone
     value: xxx
   - name: keytwo
     value: xxx
```

Quiero usar el apikey numero dos en una unas funciones especificas.

Por ejemplo solo quiero que hello2 use el apikey numero 2:

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          method: get
  hello2:
      handler: handler.hello
      events:
        - http:
            path: hello
            method: get
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero de todo es que no deberías tener claves de ningún tipo en ningún script. Para eso está SecretsManager.

Supongamos que me haces caso y creas dos secretos, uno para cada cada api-key:

- key-one
- key-two

Ahora ya no necesitas poner la key directamente en el script, sino que haces referencia a los secretos

```
custom:
  apiKeys:
    keyone:
      value: key-one
      region: us-west-2
    keytwo:
      value: key-two
      region: us-west-2
```

He modificado el formato a propósito para poder seleccionar facilmente una de las dos api-keys

Y ahora, cómo le indicamos a cada lambda qué clave utilizar? Para eso puedes utilizar las variables de entorno:

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    environment:
      API-KEY: ${self:custom.apiKeys.keyone.value}
      API-REGION: ${self:custom.apikeys.keyone.region}

  hello2:
    handler: handler.hello
    environment:
      API-KEY: ${self:custom.apiKeys.keytwo.value}
      API-REGION: ${self:custom.apikeys.keytwo.region}
```

Ahora ya solo queda modificar el script de las lambdas. Simplemente deben leer el valor de la variable de entorno y acudir a SecretsManager para recuperar el valor del api-key

```
api_secret = os.environ['API-KEY']
api_region = os.environ['API-REGION']

session = boto3.session.Session()
client = session.client(
    service_name='secretsmanager',
    region_name=api_region
)

response = client.get_secret_value(
    SecretId=api_secret
)

if 'SecretString' in response:
    api_key = response['SecretString']
```

No olvides modificar el rol de la lambda para que pueda acceder a los secretos